# Do talents that halve damage taken stack?

Tags: damage, stacking, shadow-of-the-demon-lord

I know talents that add boons or bonus damage stack fairly simply.

However, the Juggernaut Expert Path from A Glorious Death and the Prince of Darkness Expert Path from Tombs of Desolation both have a talent where incoming damage is halved, though under different circumstances.

My question is, assuming a character has both these talents and meets the specific circumstances for each one, how do they interact? Do you halve damage and then halve again afterwards, or do they achieve an identical effect and therefore having one makes the other obsolete?

Answer (score 3):

## Rules as written, you do not get the benefit of both talents.

Per the Core Rulebook, p.39:

> When a creature or object takes half damage, divide the total damage by 2 and round down to the nearest whole number. You halve damage only once, regardless of how many times you are instructed to halve it.

I have looked on the Shadow of the Demon Lord Reddit, MeWe, Discord and Facebook pages, and have found nothing to the contrary. I then posed the question in the private Facebook group "Shadow of the Demon Lord Cult", and [got a response from the creator (Rob Schwalb)](https://www.facebook.com/groups/888476107901122/permalink/2545855225496527/):

> Schwalb Entertainment, LLC: They don’t stack. You halve the damage once.

I have seen a house rule where for each extra talent giving the ability to halve damage you increase the reduction by 1. So two talents that allow you to take half damage would mean taking 1/3 damage, three talents would be 1/4 damage, etc. This is a house rule only.